# Why is the link not being generated here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have these two methods in my signeduser model:

```
def build_invitation
  self.create_invitation
end

def generate_url
  self.invitation.invitation_url = "http://www.dreamstill.com/?id=#{self.invitation.id}"
end
```

I also have a custom rake task that calls these two methods:

```
task :generate_url => :environment do
  SignedUser.all.each do |user|
    user.build_invitation
    user.generate_url
  end
end
```

It seems that although the invitations were create, the urls were not generated for the invitation. Maybe it's because I did not save it? How do I fix the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're forgetting to save the result of your assignment and it's being lost when the object is discarded.

```
task :generate_url => :environment do
  SignedUser.all.each do |user|
    user.build_invitation
    user.generate_url
    user.save(false)
  end
end
```

Passing `false` as an argument to `save` avoids running the validations and basically forces a save. This may help with situations where the user record is invalid, such as new requirements being imposed on an old record, for some reason but you want to save this one change anyway.

Comment: but I'm saving the invitation and not the user... will `user.invitation.save(false)` save the invitation?

Comment: the general premise is right, it should be `user.invitation.save(false)` in my case though

Comment: My bad, it's actually the invitation which needs to be saved as you've pointed out, but this is something you should shunt into the `generate_url` method to avoid this very sort of confusion.